# PHP echo and <?= tag

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to figure out why and what exactly this is, I've tried finding documentation on Google but without know the terminology I can't really find a reliable search. I saw a code similar to this

```
<?php
  $text = "Hello World";
?>
<?=$text?>
```

This will echo `Hello World` so what is it exactly, since it's doing the same as echo. Also doesn't seem like a big space junky either, As I've tried this on [IDE ONE](http://www.ideone.com)

Can someone give me a rundown or at least link me to the terminology and other short hands.

Comment: `<?=` is short open tag format for "echo". Short open tags must be ON in order for it to work. Another short tag is `<?` which is equivalent to `<?php` => http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php & http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Did you read documentation about mentioned echo?

Comment: It's explained in the [echo manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Comment: `<?=$text?>` is abbreviation for `<?php echo $text; ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- since PHP 5.4 short tags is no longer needed to use it.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, and never thought to look at the echo documentation because I wasn't quite sure what it was doing. I knew it was outputting the text, so not 100% sure. Thanks guys. I will read the links provided that is all I needed.